# Custom tool error: Failed to generate file file: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#

I have inherited a large mvc3 solution and I am trying to upgrade my data project from a target framework of 4 to 4.5.2, but I am getting a most uninformative error message
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Custom tool error: Failed to generate file: Value does not fall within the expected range.  RSINET.MVC.Data C:\Users\rpeterson\Desktop\web_app\product\RSINET.MVC.Data\Properties\Settings.settings 1

The data project is using we are using T4, LinqToSQL, miniprofiler, glimpse, StructureMap, and MVC3 (which of course I would be happy to upgrade).  I have yet to figure out which custom tool it is complaining about.  There is a Settings.Settings file that it seems to associate to the error, but I have not been able to tell what exactly it is being used exactly.  I would speculate that is has something to do with the DataConnections in the Server Explorer since there are a number of connection strings, but I am not 100% sure on that one.  I have been going through the process of removing remove 3rd party tools and references to make the error go away and try and identify what exactly is throwing this error, but I am still groping for ideas.  Anyone else have an idea?[image: Settings.settings]
[image]

Comment: That sounds like T4 to me.

Comment: I may have stumbled across an answer.  I just deleted the default settings and my data project is miraculously building with a 4.5.2 target framework.